# Target Integrity Error while building on iOS 15 Beta 5

Tags: ios15

While I'm trying to run application on simulator I'm getting below warning

**Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Cordova'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'AbbWorld' from project 'AbbWorld')
Target 'Cordova' (in project 'CordovaLib')
Target 'Cordova' (in project 'Pods')**

Even though its just a warning I should be able to run the application but I'm unable to do so

Issue is on Xcode 13 Beta 5. Working fine on Xcode 12.5

[podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TgaC.png)

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, we are going to need a lot more context than just the error in order to help you, please edit you post to provide more details

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the salesforcemobilesdk-cordovaplugin, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jorge Im still building the app on xcode 12.5.1. Kindly let know if you find any solution